# Stuck on splash screen, error loading shared library

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded Adobe flash player from the site and when I follow the commands (move adobe flashplayer plugin dir in `/usr/lib` ) to install it it gives me

```
error:libsudo_util.so.0: error while loading shared libraries:cannot open shared object. No such file or directory.
```

After this my Ubuntu stops working. i cannot open terminal nor any file or folder.

After logging out my Ubuntu screen sticks at the purple screen.
I also tried recovery mode but it gives me

```
apt-get error: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.16:cannot open shared object file.
```

I cannot even run commands like `sudo apt-get gedit` in recovery mode. I get `error while loading shared libraries`.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Exactly what command did you use to move the flashplayer plugin ?

Comment: I think I ran sudo mv -r adobe-flashplayer-plugin /usr/lib command.

Comment: That looks safe enough ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you accidentally moved some/all shared libraries in the `/usr/lib` directory.

I would boot from a Ubuntu Live CD/USB or recovery mode and look if the `/usr/lib` directory still exists. If not maybe you just renamed it. Search for recently modified directories.

The Live system should give a good reference on how the content of the directory should look like. From the errors you mentioned: `libapt-pkg.so*` should be located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and
`libsudo_util.so*` should be located in `/usr/lib/sudo`.

Comment: Thanks!. I did what you said and I came to know that there is no 'lib' folder in my root directory. After extensive searching via terminal I saw my Lib folder was moved to my home directory in the adobe flash player directory. I then Copied it again to my root directory and everything works fine now.